# Can be instantiated the type AutomationElement given an AutomationId value?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ui-automation

I would like to know, in **.NET**, if the (managed)*Microsoft UI Automation* framework provides some way to instantiate an `AutomationElement` type given the `AutomationId` value of a window, suppressing this way the need to search the window by a window handle or other kind of identifiers.

A pseudo example written in VB.NET to understand my purpose:

```
Dim automationId As Integer = 1504
Dim element As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromAutomationId(automationId)
```

Comment: The best I could find was [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349646(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise I'd say construct your own classes (if possible) and shadow/override the `AutomationId` property. Then whenever its setter is executed you store the "window"/"control" in a global, shared list/dictionary.

Comment: @Visual Vincent Thankyou, the "problem" I see is with that solution it is a search methodology and also it needs an AutomationElement to search through its elements, a expensive find algorithm. I would like to know if exists a more "direct" way to avoid all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no.  Any automation property is a property of the element.  Automation elements don't necessarily correspond to HWNDs (every HWND has an automation element, but very few automation elements have HWNDs, particularly in modern UI frameworks), and therefore a tree walk is required.   Also, the nice thing about UI Automation is that the tree walk occurs *on the provider side*, not in your application, reducing the number of cross-process calls.